# Add reactions outside of async function discord.py

Tags: discord.py

I have a function outside of  the async function which needs to send messages (ctx.send), add reactions (msg.add_reaction) and do something on reaction added. The problem is that I can't use await to do this stuff. I looked online and found `bot.loop.create_task()` and put every await code I had into it. `bot.loop.create_task(bot.get_channel(confirmationsChannel).send(embed=embed))` to send an embed it looks like this and it works but when I want to add a reaction `bot.loop.create_task(confirmationEmbed.add_reaction("✅"))` it shows an error `"AttributeError: '_asyncio.Task' object has no attribute 'add_reaction'"`. Can someone explain to me how would I achieve that?

Comment: The internal task loop is for asyncio things. Don't mess with it. Can you edit in the full code sample you have tried, and a clear description of what you want to do? You've added the reaction, but then what? Do you want to wait for people to click it? How long? etc.

Comment: [asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(coro, loop)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html?highlight=asyncio%20run_coroutine#asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe) can be used to run await code outside asynchronous environments.